# redirecting from faux .aspx url

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

Our company website contains an SSL page for purchasing products from our small online store. It's not a full-blown e-commerce site, just an asp.net order form that uses email.

The website itself is designed by a third party, and every link they have for our online store is incorrect and directs the user to a non-existent .aspx page. I was able to go through all of the pages to change the link, but as a precaution, I wanted to create an empty page which will be at the URL of the wrong link, and use the meta refresh HTML command to forward to the right page.

However, apparently I can't just create a plain HTML page with the .aspx extension. I guess the browser expects to see more. I don't want to have to create an entire asp.net page just to do this, so I'm hoping someone knows of a way to fool the browser into thinking it's an .aspx page just to run the HTML meta refresh command.

The website is hosted on our Microsoft server. And by the way, I don't have access to the IIS for our website.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a bit hacky, but perhaps create a directory called "whatever.aspx" and make the "index.html" file in that directory the page with the redirect.

Comment: @OxGuy3 An interesting idea. Unfortunately, it just returned an asp.net runtime error. But thanks,